# Compile a project in VHDL on Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Compiling a project in VHDL on Modelsim I encountered the following errors:** Error: C:/Users/User.User-PC/Desktop/progettoasi.vhd(15): near "architecture": syntax error ** Error: C:/Users/User.User-PC/Desktop/progettoasi.vhd(24): near "reg_process": (vcom-1576) expecting END.

This is my code:

```
enter code here
 library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
 use ieee.numeric_std.all;

  entity asic is
  port ( ck,reset:in std_logic;
  req_in: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  req_out: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  req_in_word, response_in_data, nanoinstruction: in std_logic_vector(49 downto 0);
  req_out_word, response_out_data: out std_logic_vector(49 downto 0);
  response_in, response_out_ack, req_out_ack: in std_logic;
  response_out, response_in_ack, req_in_ack: out std_logic);
  end asic;

  architecture asic_rtl of asic is
  signal state,next_state: integer;
  signal tmp_source1,tmp_source2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal value1, value2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  type regsarray IS array (0 to 2**12-1) OF std_logic_vector(49 downto 0);
  signal reg_file : regsarray;
  signal tmp_nanoinstruction: std_logic_vector(49 downto 0);
  signal rw: std_logic;

 begin

 reg_process:process(ck,reset)
  begin
 if reset='1' then
    state<=1;
 elsif rising_edge(ck) then
    state<= next_state;
 end if;
 end process reg_process;
```

*emphasized text*

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This code has a syntax error at line 34 - you are missing the final `end;`. It does not have syntax errors at line 15 or line 24.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matthew Taylor: the architecture needs to be closed.
Try to add the following to the end of your file:

```
end asic_rtl;
```